# Dialog fragment to fragment with custom resyclerview

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments

I have a `RecyclerView` in a fragment and in this `RecyclerView` adapter, I have `onClickListener` to the `RecyclerView` row button. When I clock on the button in `RecyclerView` it displays a `DialogFragment`.

My question is:
I want when I click in a `DialogFragment` button it should call a fragment function. I have tried everything like

```
((Fragment)getTaregetFragment()).func();
```

And

```
((Fragment)getParentFragment()).func();
```

but not working for me.

Also,
I want to do a refresh to my custom `RecyclerView` in that function.
But my app stops working.
How can I do that?
Thank you

Comment: Hi @Rasheed Kaid, Welcome to StackOverflow. It would be really helpful for other people, if you could share the complete code of what you are doing or have tried, related to your question.

Comment: Also show the logcat when your app crashes.